Optimal strategy for Do Not Find The Fox
Do Not Find The Fox is an online solitaire game where you attempt to fill in a $4 \times 4$ grid without spelling the word FOX forwards, backwards, or diagonally ($8$ directions total). It comes in two variations, one with a diagonal pre-filled with $4$ O's and the other starting entirely blank.
The game starts with $5$ F's, $5$ X's, and $2$ or $6$ O's in the bag, depending on the variation. Each turn, the player selects a square on the grid to place their tile, and a random tile is drawn out of this bag and placed on this square. Play continues until FOX is spelt or the bag is emptied, or equivalently, the grid is filled up.
What is the optimal strategy, or at least a good strategy, for both variations? The game seems to be mostly luck, but it seems there is some information to be used by the player. Also, which variation favors the player more?

This game has no strategy.
Consider the following setup: Given an algorithm $A$ and a set of elements $S$ of size $n$, we can construct a random vector $X$ as follows.  The algorithm $A$ starts by picking an index $i \in [n]$, and the element $X_i$ is determined via a uniform random draw from $S$ without replacement (i.e. the chosen element $X_i$ is removed from $S$).  Then we repeat this for $n$ total repetitions.  At each stage the algorithm $A$ knows what the previous draws from $S$ were, and it isn't allowed to pick an index that it already picked earlier.  After $n$ repetitions, the vector $X$ has been fully determined and is a permutation of the original $n$ elements of $S$.
Define $P^{A, S}$ to be the distribution of the random variable $X$ produced by the above process.
Claim. For any algorithm $A$, the resulting distribution $P^{A, S}$ is equivalent to the uniform distribution on permutations of $S$, which we write as $\text{Unif}(S!)$.
Proof. By induction on $n$.  Suppose $|S| = n+1$, and the algorithm chooses an index $i$.  We can describe the distribution $P^{A, S}$ as follows: An element $X_i \sim \text{Unif}(S)$ is chosen randomly, and then the $n$ remaining elements $X_{\setminus i}$ are drawn from $P^{A[X_i], S - X_i}$ where $A[X_i]$ is the state of the algorithm after it is informed that the first draw was $X_i$.  By the inductive hypothesis, we know $P^{A[X_i], S - X_i} = \text{Unif}((S - X_i)!)$.  We have shown that, under $P^{A,S}$:

The marginal distribution of $X_i$ is $\text{Unif}(S)$.
The conditional distribution of $X_{\setminus i}$ conditioned on $X_i$ is $\text{Unif}((S - X_i)!)$.

Therefore $P^{A, S} = \text{Unif}(S!)$, QED.
This proves the claim for deterministic algorithms $A$; it also works for randomized algorithms, since the distribution produced by a randomized algorithm is just a mixture of the distributions produced by some individual deterministic algorithms, each of which is individually uniform.

From the above Claim, it follows that this game has no strategic choices, since any method of choosing locations results in the same distribution of letters on the board.  It is left as an exercise to calculate the probability of winning.
